# Get list of CheckedOut Items

Tags: list, check-out

I found the following code which works like a charm as is...
How do I modify it for a specific (known) list.

```
# enter your site URL
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://sp2013"

function GetCheckedItems($spWeb)
{
Write-Host "Scanning Site: $($spWeb.Url)"
foreach ($list in ($spWeb.Lists | ? {$_ -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary]})) {
Write-Host "Scanning List: $($list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)"
foreach ($item in $list.CheckedOutFiles) {
    if (!$item.Url.EndsWith(".aspx")) { continue }
    $writeTable = @{
    "URL"=$spWeb.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($spWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)");
    "Checked Out By"=$item.CheckedOutBy;
"Author"=$item.File.CheckedOutByUser.Name;
    "Checked Out Since"=$item.CheckedOutDate.ToString();
"File Size (KB)"=$item.File.Length/1000;
"Email"=$item.File.CheckedOutByUser.Email;
    }
    New-Object PSObject -Property $writeTable
}
foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
    if ($item.File.CheckOutStatus -ne "None") {
        if (($list.CheckedOutFiles | where {$_.ListItemId -eq $item.ID}) -ne $null) { continue }
        $writeTable = @{
        "URL"=$spWeb.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($spWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)");
        "Checked Out By"=$item.File.CheckedOutByUser.LoginName;
    "Author"=$item.File.CheckedOutByUser.Name;
        "Checked Out Since"=$item.File.CheckedOutDate.ToString();
    "File Size (KB)"=$item.File.Length/1000;
    "Email"=$item.File.CheckedOutByUser.Email;
        }
        New-Object PSObject -Property $writeTable
    }
}
}
foreach($subWeb in $spWeb.Webs)
{
GetCheckedItems($subWeb)
}
$spWeb.Dispose()
}

GetCheckedItems($spWeb) | Out-GridView

# alternative output file
# GetCheckedItems($spWeb) | Out-File c:\CheckedOutItems.txt -width 300
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
# enter your site URL
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://sp2013"
$listName = "Your List Title"

function GetCheckedItems($spWeb)
{
    $list = $spWeb.Lists[$listName]
    Write-Host "Scanning List: $($list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)"

    foreach ($item in $list.CheckedOutFiles) {
        if (!$item.Url.EndsWith(".aspx")) { continue }
        $writeTable = @{
        "URL"=$spWeb.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($spWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)");
        "Checked Out By"=$item.CheckedOutBy;
    "Author"=$item.File.CheckedOutByUser.Name;
        "Checked Out Since"=$item.CheckedOutDate.ToString();
    "File Size (KB)"=$item.File.Length/1000;
    "Email"=$item.File.CheckedOutByUser.Email;
        }
        New-Object PSObject -Property $writeTable
    }
    foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
        if ($item.File.CheckOutStatus -ne "None") {
            if (($list.CheckedOutFiles | where {$_.ListItemId -eq $item.ID}) -ne $null) { continue }
            $writeTable = @{
            "URL"=$spWeb.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($spWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)");
            "Checked Out By"=$item.File.CheckedOutByUser.LoginName;
        "Author"=$item.File.CheckedOutByUser.Name;
            "Checked Out Since"=$item.File.CheckedOutDate.ToString();
        "File Size (KB)"=$item.File.Length/1000;
        "Email"=$item.File.CheckedOutByUser.Email;
            }
            New-Object PSObject -Property $writeTable
        }
    }
}

GetCheckedItems($spWeb) | Out-GridView
$spWeb.Dispose()

# alternative output file
# GetCheckedItems($spWeb) | Out-File c:\CheckedOutItems.txt -width 300
```

Comment: Spot on, I'm still learning the ropes... ;) That is so simple... Thanks a Million.